Add timer to RunLoop that's already running in iOS
I have this code:

    let timer1 = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
      print("FOO1")
    }
    let timer2 = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
      print("FOO2")
    }
    let timer3 = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
      print("FOO3")
    }
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "")
    queue.async {
      RunLoop.current.add(timer1, forMode: .common)
      RunLoop.current.run()
    }
    queue.async {
      RunLoop.current.add(timer2, forMode: .common)
    }
    queue.async {
      RunLoop.current.add(timer3, forMode: .common)
    }

In the current code, only timer1 is run. This is strange, because timer2 and timer3 are added to a running runloop. I recall in the main run loop (which is already running so I don't have to call run again), I can simply add timers I want to add, and the timers will get triggered no problem.
My findings:

If I move RunLoop.current.run() to the last async block, then all timers will be run.
If I add RunLoop.current.run() to all the 3 async blocks, only timer1 is run.
Changing .common to .default mode won't help

I am wondering why is my runloop behaving differently than the main runloop, and how can i mimic the behavior of main runloop?

Actually, run is a blocking method (see here : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop, it says "permanent loop"). So it blocks the queue (and, in fact, from what I gathered, the whole thread), and the two last timers are never added to it.
One possible solution is to call Runloop.current.run() as the last instruction of your thread.

As a side note, the main loop is likely ran implicitly, at the end of your script. That's why the timers get added without any problem.

what do you mean by "run implicitly"? isn't it also infinite loop?

And how can i mimic the main runloop behavior?

Strange, if i do RunLoop.current.run(), then call print("ABC") on the next line, then ABC is printed out, meaning that the run call does not block.

Okay, then there's something  (possibly many things) I don't understand. I'm sorry...

np! the discussion is helpful
